# fb-messenger-api url scheme for specific user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios9, url-scheme

We can open the facebook messenger using the url scheme:

```
   @"fb-messenger-api://"
```

I get the user Id by doing `FBSDKGraphRequest`  `WithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"`

and I get my friend id by `result[@"data"][@"id"]` which looks something like:

```
1234565657686
```

and it didnt worked. It just opens the messenger, but not the conversation window of my friend.

This is how I Actually try to open messenger:

```
NSString *customURL = @"fb-messenger-api://user/1234565657686";

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
         canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
    }
```

How can I open the fb messenger's particular user conversation window by using url scheme ?

Comment: Taggable_friends are for tagging. Nothing else

Comment: then the "friends" param should work with the way I am trying to do ?@WizKid

Comment: No. You are trying to open messenger for a specific user. You are not tagging people

Comment: no im not tagging people. Im just getting the user id of my freinds. Is user id different for taggable friends/invitable friends/freinds ?

Comment: /me/taggable_friends gives you taggable friends to tag. If you are not tagging people don't use that endpoint

Comment: do I need to use /me/friends endpoint  and get the user id to open the messenger for specif user ?

Comment: There is no supported way to open messenger for a specific user.

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the reply.